# How to access Mongoose Schema Attributes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am fairly new to using Mongoose and MongoDB. I am working on a register / login page. The register function works fine, storing the user account onto the database, but my problem is with logging in. What I am trying to do is get the 'password' attribute from the matching user off of the database, to match against the password that the user enters. This is my login function.

```
router.post('/logSubmit', function(req, res, next) {
var gusername = req.body.username;
var gpassword = req.body.password;

User.count({
    'credentials.username': gusername
}, function(err, count) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(count);
    if (count > 0) {

      // Where I need to pull password attribute from the database

    } else {

      // Wrong username or password

    }
});
});
```

I have looked all over the internet on how to read an attribute from a database entry, but I can't find anything. I feel like it is something very simple, but I guess I don't know the syntax. The name of my model is User. I figured it would be something like:

```
User.find({ username: gusername }, function(err, user) {
if (err) throw err;

var getpassword = user.password;
console.log(getpassword);

});
```

I half-thought that would work, but it didn't. How do I access the password attribute from the database?? Thanks.

EDIT:

This is what my user accounts look like stored in my database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "569e5344d4355010b63734b7"
},
"credentials": {
    "username": "testuser",
    "password": "password1234"
},
"__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on how `User` was defined in mongoose. Can you paste your Schema definition?

Comment: `var userSchema = new Schema({
    credentials: {
        username: String,
        password: String
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know how to format a code comment. I've hardly used this site

Comment: Shouldn't you get the password by `var getpassword = user.credentials.password;`?

Comment: I tried that and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, now I see that you are using `count`, if you want the data you need to do a `User.find()`. Count will give you just that.. a count.

Comment: Yes, I use count in order to see if the username that the user is trying to log in with exists. If it returns >1, then I know that they are logging in with a valid username. The next step is to get the 'password' attribute from that username on the database. And that's where I am stuck

Comment: If you look at the second code box on the post, you will see, that is where I was using User.find(), but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `find` query is sufficient for your purposes. If a non-null `user` object is retrieved from the `find` query, you have a guarantee that it is a user with a password.

```
User.find({ 'credentials.username': gusername }, function(err, users) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // 'users' is an array of the User objects retrieved.
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    // Do something with the password.
    // The password is stored in user.credentials.password
    console.log(user.credentials.password);
  });
});
```

Comment: console.log(user.credentials.password);
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/index.js:124:33)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting, but that's what my console prints

Comment: I've corrected the bug in my solution. I apologize for the error.

Comment: You can format your text by using placing the text between backticks (the special character that looks like an `'` but slants a lot more). You can also click the `help` tab on the right side of the comment box to learn how to format text with Markdown.